# How to know if listview.item with index 2 is added or not

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm trying to indetify by button click if `listview2.item(2)` exists on `listview2` or not:

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button8.Click
    If ListView2.Items.Count.Equals(2) Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Row with index 2 is found"
    End If
End Sub
```

`ListView2.Items.Count.Equals(2)` doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item(2) is actually the third one as the index of the items starts with 0. If you want to check if item with the index 2 is there you need to check if the items count is at least 3.

```
If ListView2.Items.Count >=3 Then
    TextBox1.Text = "Row with index 2 is found"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
  If Not ListView2.Items(2).ToString() = "" Then
    Msgbox("Item exists")
  End If
```